# See all unread inbox messages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange.com, global-inbox, network-profile

Is it possible to see all the unread messages for the StackExchange network even after one of the unread messages has been viewed? I've noticed that the unread message count in the upper-right corner (circled in red) disappears after clicking just one of the unread messages.

Comment: I was surprised when I noticed that all of my other inbox notifications disappeared after reading just one of the messages in my inbox.

Comment: You can see your entire list of messages if you click StackExchange > Inbox

Comment: Yes, but the unread messages are not clearly marked as such. How can I view all of my unread messages (instead of all recent messages?)

Comment: Reading one makes them *all* read

Comment: Yes, that's the bug that I'm reporting. :/

Comment: You can, however, see all the responses on a given site if you visit your profile->responses

Comment: Does this show ALL the responses, or just the unread messages?

Comment: It highlights the unread ones.

Comment: All I do is middle-click the title of the 'unread' notification to open a new tab, read the response (possibly reply if required), and close the tab. The Stack Exchange drop down is still open in my original tab and still highlighted. Personally I don't get more than about 4 notifications at a time, so it's not a big deal for me, but I can see where leaving them unread would be helpful if you constantly have around 30 or so notifications

Comment: This isn't actually a bug (the behaviour is by design), so I'm switching this to just a feature request.

Comment: It's not really *reading* that make the number reset, it's opening the Inbox tab of the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ box. Right now there is no check if you actually click any item.

Comment: This was effectively implemented by the [recent inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251), since individual notifications are marked as read or unread, and you can filter your inbox to just the unread notifications (within the last 50 or so).

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised this is still an issue 5 years later. It can be realy annoying sometimes, to double check you have read everything.

I have made a litte mockup, how it could look like:

[image]

Please consider give the user some feedback about what is read and what it is not.

Comment: Why not just use the blue shading that signals "new message" now?  Instead of clearing it from all inbox messages, it could be cleared only from the ones that have been read.