# Highlight unread messages on the inbox page on stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, stackexchange.com, global-inbox

The following URL is very handy in that it shows me an expanded view of my inbox, but it does not highlight unread messages. This makes it very hard to differentiate which messages I need to read or not.

https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox

The inbox in the topbar highlights my unread messages, but marks them all as read as soon as I open it. If I have many inbox messages, it is easy to lose track of what the unread ones are.

Can we please have the **inbox tab on the profile** (not the inbox feature on the topbar) highlight unread messages and mark them as read once they've been clicked on?

---

This is not a duplicate of [See all unread inbox messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141600/see-all-unread-inbox-messages). That question is asking about the topbar inbox feature—which currently *does* highlight unread message—and the fact that it currently marks all messages as read as soon as the inbox is opened. While this is a similar topic, it is not asking about the same thing, nor requesting the same feature.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that is for the inbox in the topbar, not the inbox tab in the profile. The inbox in the topbar currently does highlight new messages, but marks them all as read which is what that question is asking about. This is a completely different question, as detailed in my question.

Comment: The other request does not really specify where, just saying "see all the unread messages for the StackExchange network even after one of the unread messages has been viewed" - natural place is exactly what you propose. So same goal, your suggestion is one way of achieving it. Personally still think it's the same request.

Comment: @ShadowWizard *"I've noticed that the unread message count in the upper-right corner (circled in red) disappears after clicking just one of the unread messages."* and the comments all seem to suggest that it is specifically asking about the topbar inbox feature to me. It seems to me that the post is suggesting that messages in that feature should only lose their highlighted status once they've been clicked on. That ios a much different feature request than what I'm requesting, and not entirely clear at that.

Answer (score 2):

As of the [recent inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251), read notifications are now grayed-out on the inbox tab of the network profile, while unread notifications have a white background. As such, I think this is effectively [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).