# How can I view unread messages?

Tags: support, data-explorer, notifications, global-inbox

At one point I had up to a hundred of unread messages.  I read many of them, but the notification icon says there are four I have not.   Because of the sheer number of the messages, I am having trouble finding the unread ones.  Is there a way to bring up the unread messages?  I am hoping there is some query I can perform via script to get this list to come up...

Related: [See all unread inbox messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141600/see-all-unread-inbox-messages)

[Inbox icon indicates an unread message, but no messages are shown under "unread"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385090/inbox-icon-indicates-an-unread-message-but-no-messages-are-shown-under-unread)

Comment: It's because of caching: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384311/377214. Either fully refreshing the page or clicking "Mark all as read" will fix it.

Comment: In this thread one user described an "Inbox (Unread)" view: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384288/241780 .  Is this view of unread messages in the inbox still available?  And no, fully refreshing the page does not fix it; I suspect there are unread messages, but they are several pages down in the Inbox.

Comment: Yes, it is still available. That's a dropdown menu; you click it to change the view.

Comment: Well if those four are not in the last 50, you're out of luck and there's no way to find them, as the full inbox was not upgraded and does not show read/unread status. But you have to explain this and have the feature request ask to change the [full inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) so that it will also show the message status and let us filter, same as we can do now in the top bar inbox.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Your comment above is wrong. The full inbox was updated and does show the read/unread status by the unread messages having a white background. You are correct, however, that there's no filter to show just the unread messages.

Comment: @Makyen well I didn't even notice, and pretty sure it was also white before the update. But anyway, personally I have over 2000 pages, so going through them, even with a script, is a no-go. This can work for one without so many messages though.

Comment: @Joachim That question was about how to view more than one unread pass of messages at a time.  This was an issue that has since been fixed.  Mine is a new problem, where the unread messages were so many that they dropped below the top 50, so were not in this list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, the list of your unread messages would be fully shown when you select the "INBOX (UNREAD)" view at the top left of the inbox popup/dropdown. However, the inbox popup/dropdown only shows the most recent 50 messages, so if you have a lot of messages, it's possible for some or all of your unread messages to not be displayed in the inbox popup/dropdown.

You can see all of your unread messages in your full inbox on stackexchange.com. There's a "[Go to full inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox)" link to your full inbox at the bottom of the inbox popup/dropdown. Within your full inbox, your unread messages will have a white background. There's no view of just the unread ones, so you will need to page through your inbox looking for the ones which are unread. Currently, there's no specific control within your full inbox to mark individual messages as read or unread. However, clicking on the link provided within a specific unread message will cause the message to be marked as read.

Once you've handled all of your unread messages, you can use the "Mark all as read" button in the inbox popup/dropdown to mark all your messages as read.

Note that, currently, just opening the inbox popup/dropdown on any of chat.stackoverflow.com, chat.stackexchange.com, or chat.meta.stackexchange.com will automatically mark all of your inbox messages as read.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I have to go through all pages of messages one by one, looking for the unread ones.